# Using custom 14.4.1 livecd on no-hardrive laptop, how can I use the CDROM temporarily to copy files into the ramdisk for that session?

Tags: 14.04, mount, live-cd

I made a custom LiveCD with the tools I needed for a no-harddrive laptop (getting to reuse some old chassis I have for basic network config tasks), using the uck.
I can boot to the new liveCD no problem. One of the tasks I want to use this for is to upgrade IOS on a Cisco router in my lab. I have other CDs that hold a variety of IOS binaries, and want to be able to (at least briefly) swap out the liveCD for the IOS cd, copy the IOS I want into /home/tmp (that I created), then TFTP it from there to the directly connected. I would prefer not to bake the IOS images into the boot iso, because code changes frequently and I don't want to have to keep recreating the image.

My problem (after opening a couple of xterms, opening the Files gui file explorer, and copying cp and ls into /home/tmp to presumably get it into the ramdrive and not needing to be called off of the boot cd):
I can ls the liveCD, and see the files in Files. When I switch disks and repeat the ls, I see zero files (like the mount is empty). I can read the CD on a different laptop with a hard drive, so suspect the loop mountpoint is bound to the livecd and can't be used for something normal but not sure. Is there a way to get around this, beyond a second cdrom (presumably external, on another USB port), or flash media (like a USB stick)?

Answer (score 1):

Bensel:

It has been in my experience, when running from the LiveCD, you cannot remove the LiveCD for any reason and expect the system to stay up.  Why not create a bootable USB thumbdrive to run off of and leave the CD-R for doing your updates?  THAT should work, because the media with the system on it remains in place, while you perform the other operations.